# Plot type for proportions (with hue)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In a classifieds website I maintain, I'm comparing classifieds that receive greater-than-median views vs classifieds that are below median in this criterion. I call the former "high performance" classifieds. Here's a simple countplot showing this:

[image]

The `hue` is simply the number of photos the classified had.

My question is - is there a plot type in seaborn or matplotlib which shows proportions instead of absolute counts?

I essentially want the same countplot, but with each bar as a % of the total items in that particular category. For example, notice that in the countplot, classifieds with 3 photos make up a much larger proportion of the `high perf` category. It takes a while to glean that information. If each bar's height was instead represented by its % contribution to its category, it'd be a much easier comparison. That's why I'm looking for what I'm looking for.

An illustrative example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to find a special case plotting function that would do exactly what you want, I would suggest to consider keeping data generation and visualization separate. At the end what you want is to plot a bar graph of some values, so the idea would be to generate the data in such a way that they can easily be plotted.

To this end, you may `crosstab` the two columns in question and divide each row (or column) in the resulting table by its sum. This table can then easily be plotted using the pandas plotting wrapper.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 5.6, 7.0

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"performance": np.random.choice([0,1], size=n, p=[0.7,0.3]),
                   "photo" :  np.random.choice(range(4), size=n, p=[0.6,0.1,0.2,0.1]),
                   "someothervalue" : np.random.randn(n) })

fig, (ax,ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3)

freq = pd.crosstab(df["performance"],df["photo"])
freq.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax)

relative = freq.div(freq.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
relative.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax2)

relative = freq.div(freq.sum(axis=0), axis=1)
relative.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax3)


ax.set_title("countplot of absolute frequency")
ax2.set_title("barplot of relative frequency by performance")
ax3.set_title("barplot of relative frequency by photo")
for a in [ax, ax2, ax3]: a.legend(title="Photo", loc=6, bbox_to_anchor=(1.02,0.5))
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8,hspace=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]